# How to get X509Certificate from an arbitrary HTTPS URL?

Tags: .net, x509certificate2

I'm using `HttpWebRequest` to pull a page from an arbitrary HTTPS URL.  In addition to the actual page result, I want to get an `X509Certificate2` instance for the remote server I just talked to.  I'm sure the public certificate is on the computer somewhere because its chain had to be validated as part of the request.  How can I get access to it?

Also, how can I make sure that the ciphersuite used in the SSL channel isn't simply the null ciphersuite?  I need to make sure that decent encryption is actually occurring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh! (duh)

```
HttpWebRequest.ServicePoint.Certificate
```

But this doesn't answer the ciphersuite part of the question, so that's still open if anyone can answer it. :)